# Multiple Validation on child form component

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have a weird problem. So at work, I have to refactor a reactive form . I have to componentize part of the form. I have to validate a child component input on the parent form but for some weird reason it doesnt work.

I tried it on my personal laptop and it's working fine. I can validate a child form, but my computer at work won't.

parent form validation:
this is just part of it.

```
corporate_credit_card: this.fb.group({
          source_attributes: this.fb.group({
            number: ['', [Validators.maxLength(21),Validators.required]]
          })
```

child form html:

```
<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <div
    class="mt-5 col"
    formGroupName="corporate_credit_card"
  >
    <div formGroupName="source_attributes">
       <input
          class="form-control"
          id="company_cc_name"
          type="text"
          name="company_cc_name"
          formControlName="name"
          placeholder="Credit Card Name"
          autocomplete="off"
        >
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

how I check if the validation is working:

```
<pre>{{this.parentForm.get('corporate_credit_card.source_attributes.number').errors | json}}</pre>
```

**I remake a something like this on my personal laptop and its working but here at work it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered some errors on your last block of code. On your template interpolation, there is no need to include `this`. In addition, you have referenced the wrong `formControlName`. It should be `number`, not `name`, since you named it as `number` on your reactive form declaration within your component.ts. You can try something like this. It should print the error validation results properly:

```
<div formGroupName="source_attributes">
  <input
     class="form-control"
     id="company_cc_name"
     type="text"
     name="company_cc_name"
     formControlName="number"
     placeholder="Credit Card Name"
     autocomplete="off"
  >
</div>


<pre>{{ parentForm.get('corporate_credit_card.source_attributes.number').errors | json }}</pre>
```

Comment: sorry. thank you. wasnt able to see this. thank you so much. appreciate the reply.

Comment: @artoo No worries :) Hope you are able to fix it smoothly!

Comment: ill fix it tomorrow. cant download the source code. lol. but ill do it tonight so they think im smart and fast. looools

Answer (score 1):

I remade this in Stackblitz.com , It worked after changing

```
corporate_credit_card: this.fb.group({
          source_attributes: this.fb.group({
            number: ['', [Validators.maxLength(21),Validators.required]]
          })
```

to this

```
corporate_credit_card: this.fb.group({
          source_attributes: this.fb.group({
            name: ['', [Validators.maxLength(21),Validators.required]]
          })
```

I renamed number to name

and then renamed the template

```
<pre>{{this.parentForm.get('corporate_credit_card.source_attributes.number').errors | json}}</pre>
```

to this

```
<pre>{{this.parentForm.get('corporate_credit_card.source_attributes.name').errors | json}}</pre>
```

so the issue you was is the `number` attribute. change it to `name`

[image: Screen Short]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ffvacz?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: sorry my bad. i was in a hurry to leave at work. because of no overtime, but ill check this after dinner. thank you. appreciate it.